# How to control colon (:) URL Query String?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to pass the Query String of ID in which colon (:) is included i.e. ABC_PD:123456.
When I am using this ID in query String session and when its redirect to another page in URL it give **404 no error found** error on webpage.

So can any one provide the solution for this so that I can pass the colon in query string and when Page will be redirect without 404 error.

Solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which language do you use? C# or VB.NET?

Comment: @Markus: I am using C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you build the URL that you redirect to, you need to encode special characters by using the [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-method:

```
var redirectTo = "/mypage.aspx?id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("id123:456");
```

This will create a query string that looks like this and will be interpreted correctly:

```
"/mypage.aspx?id=id123%3A456"
```